# Strange static initialization compiles in C#

Tags: c#, static, initialization

```
private static string Test = a ? "test" : "hello";
private static bool a = Test == "test";
```

These seem to be reliant upon each other, but at compile time become a = false" Test = "hello" regardless of the order. I think it has something to do with booleans being set to false but if someone could explain how this compiles that would be nice.

Comment: The order is only irrelevant because you get the same result in both cases. If you set `a` first, `Test` will be `null`, if you set `Test` first, `a` will be `false`.

Comment: Perhaps the reference will help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based one the C# Language specifications:

> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a
>   sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in
>   which they appear in the class declaration.

```
private static string Test = a ? "test" : "hello"; // a is false - default for bool
```

Now Test refers to the string "hello"

```
private static bool a = Test == "test"; // a remains false as Test != "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

This compiles because all the names are visible in the scope. It produces the results you experience because of default initialization of variables to 0 and order of execution.